# Show related data per level in gridView C# and ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a members table with many fields including Member_ID and Sponsor_ID. Each new registration has a sponsor which in turn is another member. So, a member is a sponsor for his referrals.  I want to create a view where each member can see his 1st level referrals(the direct referrals), 2nd level referrals (i.e. the direct referrals of his 1st level referrals) and so on upto level 10. I am thinking about creating tabs per referral level but any other view will also do.

Can anyone tell me how can I get this data per level form my database, particularly the members table?

P.S. - I am using Access database.

[DataFields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1NeD.png)

Comment: post is unclear about your db fields. to create such view you can use nested structure in GridView. it seems like mlm structure. post some more detail to help you

Comment: edited to add database fields :)